# Opencv imread does not work with relative path

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

As the title says.  I've tried to load an image with argv and with absolute path and it worked, but with relative path it doesn't. The image is in the same directory of the executable. I'm using visual studio 2013 and opencv 2.4.10 on windows 7 64 bit. How can I resolve?

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    vector< Mat > vImg;
    Mat rImg;

    vImg.push_back(imread("1.png"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("2.png"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("3.png"));


    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(true);


    unsigned long AAtime = 0, BBtime = 0; //check processing time  
    AAtime = getTickCount(); //check processing time  

    stitcher.stitch(vImg, rImg);

    BBtime = getTickCount(); //check processing time   
    printf("%.2lf sec \n", (BBtime - AAtime)
    getTickFrequency());         //check processing time  

    namedWindow("Stitching Result");
    imshow("Stitching Result", rImg);

    waitKey(0);

}
```

I tried also to use "./" "/" "//" "\" and "\",but it still not working!

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: Please provide an example code and the content of the directory that you're talking about.

Comment: I've edited the post with the code!

Comment: I think your image should be in the same folder as the sln, if you really want to do it this way :)

Comment: i copied the images in the sln folder but it still not working :/

Comment: You should check what the working directory is set to in your IDE and, if you must, copy your images there. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CTZStef said, the images must not be in the sln folder but in the folder with the VC++ project file!

Answer (score 0):

I could offer you the following way to deal with your problem:

1. In your IDE change the working directory in which your application is executed when run or debug it. Change it to the root of your data directory.
2. Start a command prompt and `cd` to the root of your data directory. Then start your application using the absolute path to it.
3. Add a compile definition which stores the absolute path of your data directory (add something like this `/DDATA_DIR=C:\where\your\data\is` to your compiler flags and in your code use `vImg.push_back(imread("DATA_DIR/1.png"));`)

Generally, if possible, I would keep your source code separate from your data and not copy it into the folder of your solution file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had problem with videos, but I think it will work for you as well. Check where your binary is being created. That becomes the current source directory to your binary. In my case, my file structure was as follows:

Project directory-

- build (where the binary was being built)
- data (where the videos were)
- include (where headers existed)

And with Cmake, my binary was being created in **/bin**. So, I provided the path as **"../data/video0.avi"** in `cv::VideoCapture cap(filepath)` (it would be `cv::imread("../whatever/path/your/file/is/in/image0.jpg")`) and it worked for me. Hope it works for you as well!